# Playing volleyball and muscle building

Tags: bodybuilding, volleyball

I got sick and lost almost all the muscles that I had built. I have recently started playing volleyball. I used to play basketball but the court seems to be a little way from where I live so I can't really go there because of other engagements. I play volleyball for nearly 30 minutes every day at home. I wonder if it will help build my upper and lower bodies.

Answer (score 6):

Volleyball is not strength training. It is a cardio/skill/power sport.

If you are a beginner with respect to strength training, then you will get stronger and see some muscle development from volleyball, but volleyball will not carry you past the very beginner stages of strength training or bodybuilding.

What you gain from strength training will transfer to volleyball: strength and power give you speed, acceleration, and vertical jump height.

What you gain from volleyball will have minimal transfer the other direction.

Answer (score 2):

Volleyball is one of the less intensive sports to play. If you do every action always on 100%, there will be some very limited growth (which is fine for most competitions). That said, the single most important thing in volleyball is proper technique. Technique can carry you to the middle leagues in most countries. In germany, muscle training is only really important starting in 3rd/2nd league, if you have proper technique.

You should always implement some core training into your warm up routine. It is a good prevention for back injuries and actually has the most impact on your spike strength on a beginner level (of course together with proper hitting technique training).

This is usually enough if you only want to play for fun. If you want to go further, start with leg training for jumping height. This helps your blocking as well as your spiking, since you have more options to spike the ball at a higher point.

Then, if you have some more time and energy on hand, continue with chest, shoulder and arm training.

Generally speaking, volleyball will not significantly boost your muscle growth and you actually should supplement volleyball with some core training to prevent back and also spine injuries.

Answer (score 1):

Volleyball won’t improve your strength. The only thing it may slightly increase is your legs (depending on position). However, If you’re looking to improve your hitting power: work on your chest, back and triceps.